# Add event handlers to grand children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some html code having hierarchy as

```
<div id="a">
    <span>
        <span id="s1">...</span>
        <span id="s2">...</span>
        <span id="s3">...</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I want to attach event handlers to s1,s2,s3 And assume that I don't know id div.span.
I tried out

```
$('#a span span').click(function(){
    alert('called');
});
```

But this does not work. Is there any other option to access grand children of an element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Try using `on()` and `> * > *`](http://jsfiddle.net/XUqTp/). The `>` means children. Without it, it would mean descendants. Then first `> *` is children, the second `> *` is the children of the children or "grand children"

```
$('#a > * > *').on('click', function() {
    alert('called');
});
```

i removed my first answer (the delegated version of `on()`) one since I can't get it to work on jsFiddle. I'm not sure why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#a>span>span').click(function(){
    alert('called');
});
```

it will look into #a and all direct child of #a that is a span it looks after direct child in that span

```
<div id="a">
    <span>
        <span id="s1">hit</span>
        <span id="s2">hit</span>
        <span id="s3">hit</span>
    </span>
    <span>
        <strong>
            <span>Wont hit</span>
        </strong>
    </span>
</div>
```

with that markup all span with the text hit will have a click event on them. jsfiddle test: http://jsfiddle.net/voigtan/TeN2q/

Comment: Working very nice..Thanks a lot voidtan

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [event delegation](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/30/event-delegation-in-javascript/) here. Assing the click handler to the parent element only, check within the handler from which element the click occured, and act accordingly. For example:

```
$('#a').click(function(e){
  e = e || event;
  var src = e.target || e.srcElement;
  if (/^s/i.test(src.id)){ /* actions */ }
  return true;
});
```